# Getting Error:Table variables and insert 'fieldnames' do not match. while exporting data from matlab to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, matlab

I am getting the Error using database.jdbc.connection/fastinsert (line 140)
Table variables and insert 'fieldnames' do not match. error while exporting data from matlab to sql. Can you please help me out. 
Below is my code.

```
conn = database('rScenariosDB','NCAT\aabhaler','','Vendor','Microsoft SQL Server','Server','A0030110GB6S942','AuthType','Windows','portnumber',1433);
for i = 1 : rScenarioCnt
    if rScenario{i}.status == 1
        ECostMax(i) = rScenario{i}.ECostMax;
        CO2EmisMax(i) = rScenario{i}.CO2EmisMax;
        ECost(i) = rScenario{i}.YearAlloc.ECost;
        CO2Emis(i) =  rScenario{i}.YearAlloc.CO2Emis ;
        EmisCostYear(i) = rScenario{i}.YearAlloc.EmisCostYear ;
        CO2EmisYear(i) = sum(rScenario{i}.YearAlloc.CO2EmisYear);

    end
end
rId = 1 : rScenarioCnt ;

colnames={'rScenarioId' ,'ECostMax' , ' CO2EmisMax','ECost' ,'CO2Emis', 'EmisCostYear', 'CO2EmisYear' };
data = table(rId',ECostMax',CO2EmisMax',ECost',CO2Emis',EmisCostYear', CO2EmisYear','VariableNames',colnames);

tablename =  'rScenarios';

fastinsert(conn,tablename,colnames,data);

curs=exec(conn,'select * from [dbo].[rScenarios]');

curs=fetch(curs);
disp(curs.Data);

close(curs);
close(conn);
```

Comment: Are you certain that the column names in `colnames` exist in the database table?

Comment: @gnovice Yes.  I am sure.

Comment: It's not SQL Server error, it's the error of your programming language (java?). You should use this language name as a tag. For example, I see that **colnames** has 2 elements less than **data**, but I don't know if it's normal or not, maybe **'VariableNames',colnames** are keywords...

Comment: The third entry in `colnames` has whitespace at the beginning: `' CO2EmisMax'`. I assume that whitespace isn't there in your database, and I know it won't be in your table `data` since MATLAB automatically removes them for table variable names. Remove that and you will likely fix your problem.

Comment: @gnovice: It was the problem of the space. Thank you very much for solving my problem. I should have checked more carefully.

Comment: Sorry for that, I though it was smth like Excel, i.e. not a language. Sorry one more time!